# Selection sort not sorting properly

Tags: c++, sorting, swap, selection-sort

The array doesn't sort properly and bubble sort and quick sort work fine. I have checked many times to find any mistakes but couldn't find one. (feel free to edit the question if it doesn't seem right)....................................
...............................................................................................................................................................................................

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int MaxElements = 500;
int compCount = 0; // keeps track of comparisons of elements in array
int moveCount = 0; // keeps track of movement of elements in array

int main()
{
    // Declarations
    clock_t before; //time before sorting
    clock_t after; //time after sorting
    double result; //Total time 
    int n; //size of set
    int sample[MaxElements]; //array

    // Prompt the user for size of set
    cout << "Enter size of set: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "---------------Selection Sort-----------------\n";
    // Generate random values into the array
    generateSample(sample, n);

    cout << "Unsorted array: ";
    printElements(sample, n);

    before = clock();
    selectionSort(sample, n);
    after = clock();

    result = static_cast<double>(after - before) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "\nSorted: ";
    printElements(sample, n);

    cout << endl << before << " " << after << "\n";
    cout << result << "\n";

    cout << "Movement: " << moveCount << endl;
    cout << "Comparison: " << compCount << endl;

}

// Swap algorithm
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i,
        j,
        current;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        current = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            compCount++;
            if (arr[j] < arr[current])
            {
                current = j;
            }
            if (current != i)
            {
                swap(arr[current], arr[i]);
                moveCount += 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, don't implement your own sort. Just use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Please remove the parts of your code that don't relate to your question. See [example]. It reduces the cognitive load of us, your audience, and may even help you figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: Vlad's answer draws attention to `swap(arr[current], arr[i]);`. I don't think you are calling the `swap` you think you are. `arr[current]` and  `arr[i]` are not pointers. This is going to work, but only by the grace of <insert deity of choice here>. One of the includes is pulling in `std::swap` and `using namespace std;` is removing the need to specify the `std` namespace.You cannot count on this, so the program may not compile with a different compiler or Standard library version.

Comment: @qwerty Since you are learning from this assignment, you could reap greater benefits by adding a part where you learn to use your debugger. Step through the code with your debugger so you can see what your code does to the array (compared to what it is supposed to do).

Comment: @JaMiT I do know how to use the debugger and I tried it multiple times but I couldn't understand where it was going wrong but thanks for the advice.

Comment: The basic gist of using a debugger is to step through the code, watching  to make sure each line performed exactly as you expected. Surprises are usually bugs, and when they are not, they are bad expectations, and that's just as bad. If you don't know what to expect, the debugger can't help you. When you get to longer, more complicated programs you'll have to read the debugger's documentation and learn to to set breakpoints (so you can quickly get to the code you want to step through) and how to get a backtrace (so you can see how the program got to the breakpoint or crash site).

Comment: @qwerty In this case, the bad behavior involves what happens to the array. So you would set a breakpoint on the only line that manipulates the array, specifically `swap(arr[current], arr[i]);`. Watching the array before and after this line should indicate that the wrong elements are being swapped, compared to your by-hand selection sort. (There's also the property that selection sort is supposed to do at most `n-1` swaps, yet your code would usually do much more than that.) Even if that's not enough to solve the problem, you get something more specific than "doesn't work properly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This if statement

```
        if (current != i)
        {
            swap(arr[current], arr[i]);
            moveCount += 3;
        }
```

must be placed outside the inner loop that is after it.